# Sqlplus using stored procedures to update a row

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, sqlplus

This is what I have so far. When I enter valid data and run it the table updates correctly. When I run it using author numbers that I know don't exist in the table it still runs, and doesn't output the exception statements. Does anyone know why my exceptions don't seem to be working. Any help would be appreciated thanks!

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE update_authorname 
(selected_author_num IN NUMBER, 
new_author_first IN CHAR,
new_author_last IN CHAR) AS 

BEGIN
UPDATE author
SET author_first = new_author_first, author_last = new_author_last
WHERE author_num = selected_author_num;

EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND 
  THEN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('No author with this number exists: ' || selected_author_num);

  WHEN ROWTYPE_MISMATCH 
  THEN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error: There was a row type mismatch when updating');

END;
/
```

This is what I used to call the procedure:

```
BEGIN
update_authorname(6,'Emma','White');
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `update` statement doesn't throw an exception when the `where` clause isn't matched, it just fails silently.  Instead, you need to check either:

1. The row `exists` before trying to update or
2. The update changed something.

**1. The row exists**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE update_authorname 
(selected_author_num IN NUMBER, 
new_author_first IN CHAR,
new_author_last IN CHAR) AS 

BEGIN

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM author WHERE author_num = selected_author_num;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('No author with this number exists: ' || selected_author_num);
ELSE
  UPDATE author
  SET author_first = new_author_first, author_last = new_author_last
  WHERE author_num = selected_author_num;

EXCEPTION
  WHEN ROWTYPE_MISMATCH 
  THEN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error: There was a row type mismatch when updating');

END;
/
```

**2. The update made changes**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE update_authorname 
(selected_author_num IN NUMBER, 
new_author_first IN CHAR,
new_author_last IN CHAR) AS 

BEGIN


UPDATE author
SET author_first = new_author_first, author_last = new_author_last
WHERE author_num = selected_author_num;

IF @@ROWCOUNT <= 0
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('No author with this number exists: ' || selected_author_num);

EXCEPTION
  WHEN ROWTYPE_MISMATCH 
  THEN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error: There was a row type mismatch when updating');

END;
/
```

There are certainly other ways to achieve the same result, but these are the two most common.